# Asus A52JR - Keep the set through turn on/turn off

Tags: asus-laptop, ati-mobility-radeon

I am a newbie on Linux. Yesterday I installed the Lubuntu LTS on this pc (https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/A52Jr/specifications/). Everything seems fine until the firefox was slowly, the writer be with delay (e.g. when write a post on the forum).

I was suspicious that it might be something related with the GPU or CPU, therefore I went google. I found this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/local/bin && wget -Nc smxi.org/sgfxi && chmod +x sgfxi && sgfxi
```

On this site: https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=7118

I ran this script and made sudo apt-get update and upgrade it seems to be all right. The output this script is:

```
user@user:~/Documents$ sudo ./video.sh
[sudo] password for user:
--2016-06-03 10:21:45--  http ://smxi .org/sgfxi
Resolving smxi .org (smxi .org)... 209.197.72.47
Connecting to smxi. org (smxi. org)|209.197.72.47|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http: //smxi. org/sg/sgfxi [following]
--2016-06-03 10:21:45--  http ://smxi. org/sg/sgfxi
Reusing existing connection to smxi .org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified
File ‘sgfxi’ not modified on server. Omitting download.
```

> ERROR: (211) You cannot start sgfxi with sudo. Please start sgfxi
>   properly as root (use either 'sudo su -' (note the '-' at the end) to
>   become root, or login as root directly). If 'sudo su -' does not work,
>   please let the sgfxi maintainer know, and if your system has root
>   locked (why would anyone do that?) then you will have to unlock root.

See your distro manuals or help pages to fix this issue in that
case, and also make sure to update any documentation or how-to's
for running sgfxi with your distro. This means you, Ubuntu/Mint users!

Typical signs of sudo failures are respawnings of your desktop while
sgfxi is running, or failures to create directories.

Exiting script now.

Also installed the ARandR and set my two screens, one be Asus 24" via HDMI and second is Dell 17" via VGA. The laptop has a screen 15.6" but I can't turn on because the GPU don't support all screens.

After I set all option on ARandR the screens sounds nice but when I restart or turn off and turn on the option which I chose disappear and I have config all set again. How can I freeze this sets and use them all time I turned on the pc? And How can I put the Panel on the Asus 22" screen? Although I choose the option Primary for the Asus 22" screen the panel remains on the 17" screen.

I can see and edit the /home/user/.screenlayout but how can I use this script(file) to setup my set at the time turn on the pc?

Thanks and sorry about my English, if you can understand please tell me which I will try do better.